# Error on insatling npm packages in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm

I am having a project, previously it was working fine suddenly it started showing this error :-
This is a react project created using create-react-app.
Same Error for `npm install` and `npm -f install`

```
sudipt@sudo:~/Desktop/project/console-frontend$ npm -f install
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Linux 5.3.0-46-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-f" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sudipt/Desktop/hydra-python-agent-gui/console-frontend/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: @ReuvenChacha the link answer was somehow right! I had to update npm but this was stored at usr/bin/local/npm so need to run one more command after that ```hash -r```, so it worked fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should update your packages:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

Then on your project directory, remove the previously installed node_modules and package-lock:

E.g:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
```

And then install the updated packages again:

```
npm i
```

Given the context this is what I would suggest, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked

Comment: didn't work for me. somehow upgrading it through apt still installed the old version only even after doing `apt update`. eventually solved using `sudo npm i -g npm`.

Comment: It did want 1 chown fixed on first `npm install` after your steps - but it said itself what it wants you to run - then `npm intsall` finally start ed working :)

Comment: @Phoenix I think it is not a good idea to run `npm` using sudo. You can find more info on google about why this should be avoided. E.g: (https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92). What I would suggest is to check how you installed node, npm probably you also did it with sudo which is by which now isn't allowing you to initialize a project without sudo as well.