# Fresh Laravel (latest) installation give NPM error

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install Laravel inside mine server with IU (npm) but i'm getting the follow error:

Does anyone know the solution for this problem:

```
    npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/xxxx/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried this? [Error on installing npm packages in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127889/error-on-insatling-npm-packages-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Federico yes i have tried this already and getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try install the latest stable version of Node, the 8.x version is a bit old, the latest LTS is the 12.
Take a look at this guide, it offers three way to update and manage node versions.

[Update node js version](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved, I have redownload the Laravel application with --prefer-dist
that solved the problem for me.
Thank you everyone for your reply.